# Checkbox becomes redundant after returning to a view

Tags: android, listview, checkbox, view

I am trying to have a checkbox on my homepage, which when checked, should take me to an another view, else, displays an error message on the same view.

This works fine the first time only. If unchecked, it displays the error, and if checked, renders the next view.

However, when I return to this homepage using back button, this time the checkbox becomes redundant. Even unchecking it renders the next page correctly.

If I remove all the views of the ViewGroup, it removes them permanently, and the homepage is empty once I return to it.
I believe the checkbox needs to be reset every time I return to the view.
However, I am unable to do the same.

Please find my code below (I am a beginner to Android development):

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public static final String EXTRA_MESSAGE="com.android.AI";
    public boolean isCheckBoxClicked=false;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
    //isChecked is the onClick attribute for checkbox in the main.xml here
    public void isChecked(View view){
        boolean isChecked = ((CheckBox) view).isChecked();
        if(isChecked){
            isCheckBoxClicked = true;
        } else {
            isCheckBoxClicked = false;
        }
    }
    //Send message is onClick for a submit button
    public void sendMessage(View view){
        if(isCheckBoxClicked) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, SeniorTeam.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        } else {
            TextView acceptTerms = new TextView(this);
            acceptTerms.setTextSize(15);
            acceptTerms.setText("Please accpet terms and conditions before proceeding");
            ViewGroup terms = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.activity_main);
            terms.addView(acceptTerms);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I see this, you don't need to be able to go back by using the back Button, do you?

In case you don't there are 2 solutions

Easy: 
Add this line to your verry last if

```
this.finish();
```

so your Activity should look like this:

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
public static final String EXTRA_MESSAGE="com.android.AI";
public boolean isCheckBoxClicked=false;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
    //isChecked is the onClick attribute for checkbox in the main.xml here
public void isChecked(View view){
    boolean isChecked= ((CheckBox) view).isChecked();
    if(isChecked){
        isCheckBoxClicked=true;
    }
    else{
        isCheckBoxClicked=false;
    }
}
//Send message is onClick for a submit button
public void sendMessage(View view){
    if(isCheckBoxClicked) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, SeniorTeam.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        this.finish();
    }
    else {
        TextView acceptTerms = new TextView(this);
        acceptTerms.setTextSize(15);
        acceptTerms.setText("Please accpet terms and conditions before proceeding");
       ViewGroup terms = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.activity_main);
        terms.addView(acceptTerms);
    }
}
```

A little more complicated:
If you use the first method pressing back will actually kick the user out of your App so if you want you can just override the method when back is pressed in your next activity for that you want to add this code int your NEXT activity(SeniorTeam.class)

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed(){
//custom actions here leave blank to render back useless
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should completely remove the `isCheckBoxClicked` variable, the `isChecked` function (and remove it from the attributes). In the sendMessage function, just call `((CheckBox)findViewById(id)).isChecked()` instead of `isCheckBoxClicked`.
The way you have it coded, there is too much room for disconnect between the variables and the UI. It is not necessary.